# Excel VBA Counting Non-Blank Cells in a Row

Tags: excel, vba, count

Okay, so I found this method for counting blanks on another thread, but it doesn't work for me. I have included my declared variables and the snip-it of code that I need help with.

```
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim countBlanks As Long
Dim ok As VbMsgBoxResult

    For x = ActiveCell.Row To ActiveCell.Row  ' specify your rows
        For y = 1 To 182 ' specify your columns

            If Cells(x, y) <> "" Then
                Exit For
            Else
                If y = 182 Then countBlanks = countBlanks + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    ok = MsgBox(countBlanks, vbOKOnly)
```

The rest of my macro is centered around what cell is currently selected. I need to be able to count all non-blank cells in whatever row is selected. The number of columns is always a constant - 182. With the data I'm testing, I should be getting 49 non-blank cells, or if I did something wrong, 133 blank cells. Honestly, either result would be fine. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I currently have the result going to a Msgbox so I can test the results, but I will want this value to be set to another variable. I need to execute different sections of code based on how many blank cells there are in the row with the selected cell.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That code doesn't make a lot of sense. Why not just use COUNTBLANK?

Comment: I tried about 20 different variations of COUNTBLANK, COUNTIF, COUNTA; none of them worked. They all returned a count of 0. I have the issue corrected now, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work at all; that code is for counting consecutive blank cells and it's not what you need

```
Dim R As Long, countBlanks As Long
Dim Cell As Range

R = ActiveCell.Row
countBlanks = 0
For Each Cell In Range(Cells(R, 1), Cells(R, 182))
    If Cell = "" Then countBlanks = countBlanks + 1
Next Cell
MsgBox countBlanks
```